# Java RESTfull web service with tomcat and eclipse gives 404

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat

I have seen a lot of people asking similar questions here but none of their solutions work for me. I am trying to create a REST service through eclipse and tomcat but I keep getting a 404 page.

My Java Class:

```
package com.audiencescience.rtbtools.requestvalidator.servlet;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/bidChecker")
public class BidCheckerRESTService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response testGet() {
        return Response.status(200).entity("<html><head></head><body>Hello world</body></html>").build();
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.audiencescience.rtbtools.requestvalidator.servlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/BidCheckerWebService/bidchecker
```

returns a 404. I am using jersey-bundle 1.18

Comment: it clearly says the url is incorrect. no resource found at this url.. as per you web.xml.. all your url should contain /rest/*..but you dont have that in your url

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `url-pattern` setting in your `web.xml`, your web service URL should be `http://localhost:8080/BidCheckerWebService/rest/bidChecker` i.e. you need to include `/rest/` in your URL, and your context should match that specified in your `@Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Your rest servlet is mapped to `/rest/*` so your URL should be like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/BidCheckerWebService/rest/bidchecker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the url-pattern to be /* for your current URL to work I.e without the /rest in the path as the above answers have suggested.